# Laravel | Multiple file upload not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to save multiple photos at a time and I have verified that the request has an array of files so that is working correctly. 
dumping $request->collegeBrochures shows:
[image]

However I have some logic error while saving those files from request. this code is not working

```
   if ($request->hasFile('collegeBrochures')) {
        $files = Input::file('collegePhoto');
        $names = [];
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $name = 'brochure-'.$college->id.'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            array_push($names, $name);
            $file->move(storage_path().'/Images/colleges/', $name);
        }
        $college->collegeBrochuresPath = json_encode($names);
    }
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: What error do you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static function fileUpload($file,$destinationPath) {
        $extenstion = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',5)),0,15).'.'.$extenstion;
        $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
        return $fileName;
    }
```

and

```
if ($request->hasFile('file_name')) {
            $file = $request->file('file_name');
            unset($data['file_name']);
            $data['file_name'] = FileUploadController::fileUpload($file,'uploads/image');
        }
```

Comment: give me up arrow